# Terraform single resource on multiple workspaces

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I have two workspaces (like dev and prd) and I have to create single resource to use on all of them.
My example is to create AWS ECR repository:

```
resource "aws_ecr_repository" "example" {
  name                 = "example"
}
```

I applied it on prd workspace and after switching to dev workspace, Terraform wants to create the same, but it exist.

After consideration I used count to create it only on prd like that:

```
resource "aws_ecr_repository" "example" {
  count = local.stage == "prd" ? 1 : 0
  name                 = "example"
}
```

and on prd workspace I use it like that:

```
aws_ecr_repository.default[0].repository_url
```

but there is a problem how to use it on dev workspace.

What is the better way to solve this?

Comment: I don't think this is something you should do. But if you really must, you might be able to achieve this by switching to your `prd` workspace and before you run `plan` use `terraform import` to import the resource into your `prd` state. But again, I'd recommend not sharing resources between stages. What for example if you want to `destroy` your `dev` stage? If you do that you will affect your `prd` stage. Really, think twice before you do something like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

since i´m not able to add a comment (i do not have enough rep)
i´m adding this as an answer.
as [Jens](https://stackoverflow.com/users/190823/jens) mentioned, best is to avoid this approach.
but you can import a remote state with something like this:

```
data "terraform_remote_state" "my_remote_state" {
  backend = "local" # could also be a remote state like s3
  config = {
    key     = "project-key"
  }
  workspace = "prd"
}
```

in your prod workspace you have to define the outputs of your repo:

```
output "ecr_repo_url" {
  aws_ecr_repository.default[0].repository_url
}
```

in your dev workspace, you can access the value with:

```
data.terraform_remote_state.my_remote_state.ecr_repo_url
```

in some cases this maybe useful, but be aware to what [Jens](https://stackoverflow.com/users/190823/jens) said: if you destroy your prod environment, you can´t apply or change your dev environment!